# MatLab silent install activation of network license fails

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to silent install matlab on a windows machine with a matlab network license file.  The install goes ok, but the activation doesn't work.  When starting matlab, it either doesn't start or I get prompted to enter a user id.

I tried adding `activationPropertiesFile=C:\activate.ini` to `installer_input.txt` and had multiple configurations of `activate.ini` which included activateDcAnon and activateOffline, but no luck.

The error logs do not help either:

```
(Jul 13, 2020 22:58:38)Starting activation process.
(Jul 13, 2020 22:58:38)Performing silent activation.
(Jul 13, 2020 22:58:39)Activating offline
(Jul 13, 2020 22:58:39)Installing license file
(Jul 13, 2020 22:58:39)Silent activation failed. Please see C:\Users\matlab\AppData\Local\Temp\aws_matlab.log for more information.
```

I looked at the following MatLab Answer, but it didn't help:

- https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/326707-activation-still-required-after-silent-activation-succeeded-matlab-r2016b

I can run the activation manually. I select online install, point to the license file, and click activate and matlab starts. But this is not a solution for automating cloud environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was I had set `enableLNU=yes` in `installer_input.txt`. Setting it to `enableLNU=no` fixed the issue.

Here is an example of creating a `installer_input.txt` file:

```bsh
@"
fileInstallationKey=9999-9999-9999-9999
agreeToLicense=yes
mode=silent
licensePath=$MATLAB_DIR\network.lic
desktopShortcut=true
startMenuShortcut=true
enableLNU=no
"@ | Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $MATLAB_DIR\installer_input.txt
```

Note that powershell Here-String `@".."@` is encoded with UTF-16.  This causes an issue with matlab installer. Pipe Here-String to Out-File to convert to ascii when writing to a file.

Now call matlab installer passing in the inputFile and force wait until installer finishes by using `&... | Out-Null` syntax:

```bsh
&$MATLAB_DIR\MathWorks\R20XXx\bin\win64\setup.exe -inputFile $MATLAB_DIR\installer_input.txt | Out-Null
```

---

The solution is to delete the `license_info.xml` file generated during silent install:

```bsh
Remove-Item -Path "C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R20XXx\licenses\license_info.xml" -Force
```

Where `R20XXx` is the version of matlab you installed.